# Passing functions beginner

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

As part my lab test this upcoming Tuesday, we're required to be able to do this question, otherwise we won't be able to do the real exam!

Here is the code :

```
 * This program finds the range between highest and lowest value of a 2-D array */

#include <stdio.h>

#define NROW 3
#define NCOL 3    

int main(void)
{
    /* declare needed variables or constants, e.g. */

    int ar[NROW][NCOL];
    int number;
    int rows, columns;

    /* prompt for the user to enter nine positive integers to be stored into the array */
    for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ )
    {
        for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 3 ; columns++ )
        {
            printf("Please enter 9 numbers " );

            scanf("%d", &number);ar[NROW][NCOL]

            /*store the number temporarily*/
            number = dispArray( ar[NROW][NCOL] )
        }
    }


    /* call the disp_arr(...) function */
    dispArray()

/* call the highest(...) function */


/* call the lowest(...) function */


/* display the range between highest and lowest number


/* Return to the operating system */


}
    void dispArray( a[][] )
    int rows, columns, a[][];

    for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ )
    {
        for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 3 ; columns ++ )
        {
            printf( "%d\t", a[][] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return a[][];

    /* Write a function where a[][] is the 2-D array
    Print the entire array to the screen. */
```

At the moment I just need to know how to print the array to the screen. My function and the way I call it in the `main` are obviously wrong.

I'm really bad at functions especially when it comes to passing arguments...which I have no idea what is it too.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!
Sam

Comment: First fix the compilation errors. Then read more about arrays and pointers.

Comment: 20 pages of "The C programming Book" is enough to solve this and may other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make these changes

```
/* call the disp_arr(...) function */
dispArray(ar)    

void dispArray(int a[][] )
```

Then, the function `dispArray` needs to have `{` and `}` around it, immediately after the `void dispArray(int a[][] )`.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all dispArray function returns void, so there is not point assigning it to number variable.
- dispArray takes two dimensional array so call should looks like `dispArray(ar);`
- dispArray signature `void dispArray(a[][])` should be `void dispArray(int a[][NCOL])`, after you pass `int a[][]` parameter to function, there is no need to create new two-dimensional array inside, remove `a[][]` from `int rows, columns, a[][];`
- as Robin stated there is no point returning a[][] from dispArray
- you forgot braces { ... } after `void dispArray(int a[][])`

Comment: Regarding the return void, it depends what you want to do. I guess there is no point returning the _array_ from `dispArray` like the current code tries to, since the caller (`main`) already has it - not a copy, but the same array.

Comment: @igleyy Hey thanks for the tips. I still have one question though. Why is it in a[][NCOL] instead of a[NROW][NCOL]?

Comment: @SamLiew it can also be a[NROW][NCOL]. If I remember correctly, there is requirement that you have to inform your function how big your array will be or at least tell it how big will be last dimension. I repeat, if I remember correctly.